# Add automatic header comments for all source files

Tags: bash, shell, perl, automation, scripting

I have a standardized way of writing comments before and after a function. 
For example before declaring any function I write,

```
 !---------------------------
 !  NAME_OF_FUNC           (no)
 !---------------------------
```

where no is the nth function in a given file containing multiple functions. 
I know that a function e.g begins with (Fortran convention) either subroutine `NAME_OF_SUB` or function `NAME_OF_FUNC`. Hence, my end result would be

```
 !---------------------------
 !  NAME_OF_FUNC           (no)
 !---------------------------
 function NAME_OF_FUNC(...)

 end function 
 !---------------------------
```

Can somebody show an example of how to write a bash script or in any other scripting language a code that can go through all my source files and the standard convention I just showed an example of?

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible.

Comment: In Perl you could use for example [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to find all the source files. Then you would have to loop through the files and read each into a string variable, then use a regex to insert the headers, and then overwrite the old file (or preferably take a backup first before overwriting)

Comment: Is it possible to show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in Perl. It does not take backup before overwriting (I would recommend that you try to improve this script and add backup functionality). It also does not add the end of subroutine marker. But it would easy to add that functionality, please try. It also assumes that you want to modify all `*.f95` files in the current directory and all its sub directories:

```
use feature qw(say state);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->new->name('*.f95')->in('.');

for my $fn (@files) {
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    my $txt = do {local $/; <$fh>};
    close $fh;
    process_txt( \$txt );
    save_txt( $fn, \$txt );
}

sub save_txt {
    my ( $fn, $txt ) = @_;

    open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $$txt;
    close $fh;
}

sub process_txt {
    my ( $txt ) = @_;

    my $i = 1;
    $$txt =~ s/^(.*(?i:function|subroutine)\s+)([a-zA-Z_]+)(\s*\(.*$)/
      do_substitution($1, $2, $3, $i++)/egmx;
}

sub do_substitution {
    my ( $head, $name, $end, $i ) = @_;

    my $line = $head . $name . $end;
    $line =~ s/\s+$//;
    my $N = length $line;
    my $cline = '!' . '-' x $N;
    my $mline = '!  ' . $name;
    my $snum = "($i)";
    my $M = (length $mline) + (length $snum);
    my $mspc = ($N > $M) ? (' ' x ($N-$M)) : '  ';
    $mline = $mline . $mspc . $snum;
    my $new_txt = join "\n", $cline, $mline, $cline, $line;
    return $new_txt;
}
```

Comment: That is great! I will hack the small bits to meet all my needs. Regarding backup, how would you conceptually recommend I save them. Do you mean create a temporary folder and dumping in all the source files before changing the actual files? And then just keep that temporary folder as a backup in case something went wrong with running the perl script?

Comment: You are welcome! *"Do you mean create a temporary folder and dumping in all the source files before changing the actual files?"* Yes exactly or simply write them to a file with a `.bak` extension. Just in case something goes wrong, yes!